# Likes value is not saving after refreshing the page in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a html and css web page and i have added a like button the codes are:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var Clicks = 0 ;
function AddClick(){
Clicks = Clicks + 1;
document.getElementById('CountedClicks').innerHTML = Clicks + 'Likes';
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<span id="CountedClicks">0 Likes</span><br>
<button onclick="AddClick()"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-"></button>
</body>

</html>
```

the vaue of likes resets to zero when i refresh the page
can you assist me pls

Comment: The value will always reset to zero on refresh, unless you store the data somewhere (i.e. database) and then fetch it and pass it to the likes counter

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it will always reset unless you store that information somewhere and re-read it whenever the site is loaded. You could look into [cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp), but while that would store the information and you could reload it, it still wouldn't be persistent and it every person who saw it would have a different value (if one at all). The only way to achieve this in an acceptable manner will be to add a database of some kind. I thought for a second maybe you could [Use a JSON file as a db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52871500/use-json-file-as-a-database-for-javascript-web-app/52871700), but you would still need to execute a script on the server side to save and read the info each time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't display the value after the refresh the page. if you want to display the value you need to store the previous value in the database or local storage.

Here I have used the local storage concepts.

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function AddClick(){
        var tempClick = localStorage.getItem('likes') === undefined ? 0 : localStorage.getItem('likes');
        Clicks = Number(tempClick) + 1;
        localStorage.setItem('likes', Clicks);
        document.getElementById('CountedClicks').innerHTML = Clicks + 'Likes';
    }
    
    //this function used to display the likes cound when you refresh
    function count() {
        var tempClick = localStorage.getItem('likes') === undefined ? 0 : localStorage.getItem('likes');
        document.getElementById('CountedClicks').innerHTML = tempClick + 'Likes';
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    
    <body onload=count()>
    <span id="CountedClicks"></span><br>
    <button onclick="AddClick()"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-"></button>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks it works but i have to edit some codes finally I found the code i was searching the codes from morning but i was not able to find it thanks

Comment: i have one more queston to ask

Comment: How to lock the like button i mean after doing this code one person can doo many likes but i want 1 like per person

Comment: it is not possible with HTML and JS.

Answer (score 1):

One way to store the click count is to use localStorage. When you load the page you check if the localStorage has "Clicks" and use that otherwise Clicks is set to 0. Every time addClick function is called you save the click count to localStorage. However Click count will only will only show in in your browser. If someone else uses your site or you use diffent browser the click count is seperate.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>

<body>
  <span id="CountedClicks">0 Likes</span><br>
  <button onclick="AddClick()"><i class="fas fa-thumbs-">Like</button>

  <script>
    let Clicks = window.localStorage.getItem('Clicks')||0
    document.getElementById('CountedClicks').innerHTML = Clicks+' Likes'

    function AddClick(){
      Clicks++
      window.localStorage.setItem('Clicks',Clicks)
      document.getElementById('CountedClicks').innerHTML = Clicks + ' Likes';
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```